# POST http://localhost:8082/public/fileUpload 404 (Not Found) when file upload button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Hi i want to upload the image into my local path.

I'm using angularjs i'm trying to do upload the image in to my local path, but i am not able to store image in my local path .

when i click upload button i am getting

```
POST http://localhost:8082/public/fileUpload 404 (Not Found)
```

but i have add the fileUpload folder on my local folder.

Here it is showing the fileUpload is not found.

Below i have add my code can any one review my code.

```
<html>

   <head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "myApp">

    <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>

      <script>  
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/public/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);

      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And when you manually copy paste the url in a browser? http://localhost:8082/public/fileUpload

Comment: Hi JP Hellemons: i am hosted my proj into my local host.

Comment: but does it give a 404 when you manually go to the url? Because there seems to be nothing to process the posted file and store it to disk.

Comment: Hi JP Hellenmons: If i run page directly "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/public/fileUpload. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." I got this error.

Comment: Add do you use the cors package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Hi JP Hellemons: yes, I using npm installer to used to run my proj into localhost

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route handler for POST `/public/fileUpload` in the application that listens on port 8082 on localhost.

It may be the case that you have a route handler for other method like GET and it may give you a response when you enter the URL in the browser but for that to work you need to have a POST handler.

See your backend code and search for `/public/fileUpload` route handlers. Make sure that POST is handled correctly.

Use `curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8082/public/fileUpload` to make sure that you get a route handled for POST.

Comment: Hi rsp: I am not using route handler in my page.

Comment: @Vinoth So why do you expect it to be handled? You need a route handler in you app that listens on port 8082.

Comment: Hi rsp: How to add route handler in this? can you tell me